# Image positioning different between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

I have two images that I want to be positioned directly on top of each other. This HTML is generated by a script every so often so I have included the CSS directly within the HTML itself.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<img id="background" 
style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; " 
src="background.png"/>
<img id="foreground" 
style="position: relative; z-index: 10; " 
src="foreground.png" border="0" usemap="#map"/>
</div>
```

It works perfectly, except in Chrome.
In firefox and Internet explorer it works 100% of the time, I can sit and hit refresh and it is fine. In Chrome sometimes on page load or refresh the background image appears to be shifted 50% to the right? 
I just did a quick test and 5/10 times (half of the time) it would appear shifted to the right on a refresh.
Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Stop using the <center> tag and use a div instead!!

Comment: does using `position: absolute` make a difference?

Comment: Thanks. I'll change the div over, my bad for a copy and paste from some older code :P Changing to absolute doesn't make any difference to the problem

Comment: Changing to using a div has also made no impact

Comment: Have you tried specifying the position of the images? example: `left: 0px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your foreground and background images are the same size, it seems as if you are trying to do this:

```
<img id="foreground" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background:url(&quot;background.png&quot;);" src="foreground.png" usemap="#map"/>
```

The `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` will center the image within its parent element.

Comment: Thanks, that would be a much more sensible way to approach this!

Comment: Check out http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp for more about backgrounds in CSS.